# Send SMS using vTiger instance

Tags: php, vtiger, smsmanager, vtigercrm

```
<?php
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Utils.php';
require_once('include/database/PearDatabase.php');
require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'includes/Loader.php';
require_once 'modules/SMSNotifier/SMSNotifier.php';
vimport ('includes.runtime.EntryPoint');

$user = Users_Record_Model::getCurrentUserModel();
GLOBAL $adb;

$tonumbers = array('994255xxxx');
$message = "Test From Ramesh";

$provider = SMSNotifierManager::getActiveProviderInstance();
if( $provider ){
    $provider->send($message, $tonumbers);
}
?>
```

Get provider instance using getActiveProviderInstance. and call send function from that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/main/WebUI.php';
require_once 'includes/Loader.php';
require_once 'modules/SMSNotifier/SMSNotifier.php';
$tonumbers = array('994255xxxx');
$message = "Test From Ramesh";
SMSNotifier::fireSendSMS($message, $tonumbers);
```